# Display/hide CCk field with custom PHP and rules or

Tags: rules, entities

I have custom variables stored in sessions, those variables are obtained remotely via URL arguments fired by remote website.

I am currently using Drupal 7, and I want to enable custom custom field A or B based on the value of the custom variable; if the custom variable is empty, it should enable field A, otherwise, enable field, B.

Can you please assist on what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

Two quick ways come to mind.

Off the cuff...

You could use the preprocess_node() hook, something along the lines of:

```
MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  if ($variables['node']->type=='THISKINDOFNODE') {

    if (empty($_SESSION['VARIABLE')) {
      unset($variables['node']->field_B;
    } else {
      unset($variables['node']->field_A;
    }

  }

  // other preprocessing here

}
```

You also could create a `node--TYPE.tpl.php` file and inside it, do something like this:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['VARIABLE'])) {
  hide($content['field_B');
} else {
  hide($content['field_A');
}
```